# Entity Translation - create a translation for all existing nodes

Tags: i18n-l10n

Using Entity Translation, is there a way to create a translation for all existing nodes, instead of translating each one manually? For other languages there is lots of missing content, and would like to create temporary English versions for all languages before they are edited.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to use a custom module that uses **hook_node_view**, as in this example:

```
function yourmodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){
   global $language;
   if (!empty($node->language) && $node->language != $language->language) {
      drupal_goto('path/to/some/temporary/version');  
   }
}
```

What the content of such `path/to/some/temporary/version` node should be is up to you. E.g. you could point to some custom 404 page.